# How to utilize available space reported by volumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsageKey?

Tags: ios, swift, diskspace

One can query iOS device for available space in several ways. One of the ways is to query using `.volumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsageKey`

This usually returns higher capacity due to the fact that there are some temporary/not important files scattered around that may be disposed of in case more important things require storing.

The question is how ?

I had tried to fillup the space on my device using the following code but once the regular capacity (eg returned by `.volumeAvailableCapacityKey` or `NSFileManager` or `boost::filesystem::space.available`) is reached my app crashes with `[general] Encountered write failure 28 No space left on device`

Here is the code:

```
func writeFile(size: Measurement<UnitInformationStorage>) {
    deleteFile()
    
    let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("output.txt")

    var megabyteOfData: [UInt8] = []
    for i in 0..<1024*1024 {
        megabyteOfData.append(UInt8(i % 0xff))
    }
    
    let data = Data(bytes: &megabyteOfData, count: megabyteOfData.count * MemoryLayout<UInt8>.stride)

    do {
        let chunks = Int(size.converted(to: UnitInformationStorage.megabytes).value)
        
        try data.write(to: filename, options: .atomicWrite)
        
        let fileHandle = try FileHandle(forWritingTo: filename)
        for i in 2...chunks {
            print("Writing \(i) chunk...")
            fileHandle.write(data)
        }
        try fileHandle.close()
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: I have managed to resolve a crash by using non-deprecated write function:

`try fileHandle.write(contentsOf: data)`

Though, original problem of tapping on available space, remains.

Answer (score 0):

I have experimented a bit and my observations are as follows:

1. It is **not possible** to do file writes that exceed regular space. In such cases, even if the OS says there is eg. 30GB free space for important usage, writing beyond **volumeAvailableCapacityKey** indicated value results in out of storage error
2. It **is possible** to download file greater in size than what **volumeAvailableCapacityKey** indicates. File is being downloaded to a location outside of applications sandbox, consuming **volumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsage** space.

   - when download is finished, in the completion handler, client gets the URL to it and may perform work on it
   - when completion handler is finished, one should assume file is gone. OS may clean it up very quickly, especially in case of bigger files
   - during execution of completion handler, client may move the file to application's folder to persist it. That can be done despite the indication of **volumeAvailableCapacityKey**. This will reduce **volumeAvailableCapacityForImportantUsage** indication.